# "Server spool directory location is invalid" when changing spooler directory to network drive

Tags: windows-10, printing

Tried changing the spool directory (printers & scanners->print server propertiers->advanced->spool folder) to a (existing) Share Point directory but getting message "Server spool directory location is invalid".

I then tried changing the directory to another network drive and got same message. I created the network drive by mapping a network drive to a folder on the local machine. I gave "everyone" read/write permissions on this folder. e.g. created `c:\QDrive\SpoolerFolder` an mapped `Q:` to `\\localhost\c$\QDrive`. Tried setting `q:\SpoolerFolder` but got said message. I can browse to `q:\SpoolerFolder` from Explorer.

Using Windows 10. I think this problem didn't happen on Windows 7. Perhaps some security patch?

Answer (score 0):

Under which *account* does the Spool Service, which *uses* this location, execute?
I'd lay dollars to doughnuts that it's *not* the same account that you're logged in with.
As such, it won't be able to use any drives that you map, because those only apply to *you*.

I'd go further and say it probably executes under an account that knows *absolutely nothing* about the Network!
Sure, it "knows" about your computer and any "local" disks attached to it but anywhere else?  Not so much.

So, what problem are you trying to solve by moving the Spool folder at all?